# Display three Model Forms and submit with single button in django

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, models

I have a complex and common required scenario in case of web pages/web development.

So i have three models like below

**models.py**

```
class model_a(models.Model):
    name_a = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class model_b(models.Model):
    forign_key_to_a = models.ForeignKey(model_a)
    name_b = models.CharField(max_length=256) 

class model_c(models.Model):
    forign_key_to_b = models.ForeignKey(model_b)
    name_c = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Aform(ModelForm):
    model = model_a

class Bform(ModelForm):
    model = model_b

class Cform(ModelForm):
    model = model_c
```

So i have above **models** and **forms**, now i need to display all of them in a single page like

```
First display Aform 
Second display Bform 
      Here the user should be able to create multiple Bform's records for Aform
Third display Cform 
      here the user should be able to create multiple Cform's records for Bform
```

I am sorry if my explanation is bad, finally what all my intention is to add the functionality like `model_a` can have multiple `model_b` records, and `model_b` can have multiple `model_c` records something like below(I can't show u the design but i hope i explained the required functionality)

name_a :

```
   name_b(first record):
         name_c(first record):
         name_c(second record):
         name_c(third record):
   name_b(second record):     
         name_c(first record):
         name_c(second record):
         name_c(third record):
   name_b(third record):     
         name_c(first record):
         name_c(second record):
         name_c(third record):
```

So can anyone please let me how to add multiple records on a single page and submit with single button

For adding the multiple records to a model by creating the forms dynamically i have tried using `Django Formsets` and jquery and i was facing this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589346/creating-a-django-form-in-formset-dynamically-like-inline-forms-in-django-admin)(of course this is another question but want to let u know what i have done in case of adding ,multiple records for a single model)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple forms to the context and access them in the template as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ a_form.as_p }}
    {{ b_form.as_p }}
    {{ c_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in the view you'd pull them out as follows:

```
a_form = Aform(request.POST)
b_form = Bform(request.POST)
c_form = Cform(request.POST)
```

Edit:
I just re-read your question and saw the part about needing multiple b_form's and c_form's on the page. You could do that with some jQuery to copy the empty when it's needed.

```
<button class="b_form_trigger">Add B Form</button>
<div class="hidden_b_form">{{b_form.as_p}}</div>
var b_form_counter = 0;
$('.b_form_trigger').click(function(){
    $(TARGET_ELEMENT).append($('.hidden_b_form > *').clone());
    // Then you will need to rename all of the inputs
    $(TARGET_ELEMENT).find('input').each(function(){
        // Need to add a prefix to the name field so we know what form we have.
        $(this).attr('name', 'b-form-'+b_form_counter+$(this).attr('name'));
    });
});
```

Then in your views.py file you can access each of the forms like this:

```
counter = 0
b_forms = []
while 'b-form-%sname_c' % counter in request.POST:
    b_forms.append(Bform(request.POST, prefix="b-form-%s" % counter))
    counter += 1
```

You'll likely want to do something a bit more robust to support adding and removing of the forms, but this how I've been able to do this in the past.

Comment: But here the functionality is adding multiple forms records of a model on a page by using some jquery like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589346/creating-a-django-form-in-formset-dynamically-like-inline-forms-in-django-admin

Comment: Sorry Shiva, I missed that on the first go around. I've added the basics of a method to my answer.

Comment: Shiva, the approach is fine. In fact, it's better than the one I've laid out here. You just need to solve that the bug in the other question.

Comment: yeah thats what i am frustated about, frankly wasted nearly 2 days to find out why its not working when i rendered the formset form fields individually, whether there is any problem is the javascript or any other thing ? Can u please look at that issue and help me out with that ? so that it will be used for sure to others too ?

Comment: Yes, I've added a comment to that one asking a question. Let's take the conversation over to that question.